# hash password using aws-crypto

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption, amazon-kms

I wonder how one would hash a password using aws-crypto (aws-encryption-sdk-javascript).
I already used the `@aws-crypto/client-node` library to do some symmetric encryption using KMS.

```
import { KmsKeyringNode, encrypt, decrypt } from '@aws-crypto/client-node';

const keyring = new KmsKeyringNode({
  generatorKeyId: "keyid"
});

const { result } = await encrypt(keyring, cleartext);
const { plaintext } = await decrypt(keyring, result);

console.log(plaintext);
```

My problem using this approach for encrypting password is, that i am still able to decrypt the passwords. I don't need this functionality since i only want to encrypt the passwords and check other strings using the same encryption against those encrypted ones to see if they match.

How would one do this with `aws-crypto` and KMS?

Comment: Not aware that aws-crypto covers the case where you don't need to be able to decrypt the data. Could you just use regular salted password hashes?

Comment: Educational nitpick: _"encryption"_ is the wrong word to use when you don't want the decryption part (aka "one way encryption").  The word you're looking for is "hashing".

Comment: @jarmod valid question. i just wanted to use a solid encryption/hashing implementation in my aws environment. what would you suggest to use then on nodejs lambdas? bcrypt?

Comment: I think bcrypt is quite popular and has a good interface. Or there are solutions that don't require third-party packages, for example https://ciphertrick.com/salt-hash-passwords-using-nodejs-crypto/

Comment: @jarmod could you please add your suggestions as an answer? makes sense to me not to require aws-crypto at all. will check out bcrypt again. i was hesitant to use it since i had in mind that it needed to compile some native modules back in the day when i used it which,.. failed sometimes on various CI envs. + for suggesting native crypto module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aws-crypto client-side library is primarily aimed at encryption/decryption use cases. If I understand your use case, I think a regular salted password hash would be appropriate.

The [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) package is quite popular and has a good interface. Or there are solutions that don't require third-party packages, for example [using the native Node.js crypto module](https://ciphertrick.com/salt-hash-passwords-using-nodejs-crypto/).

Comment: Thanks for that tip. Especially for the native crypto package. Since i deployed this function to an aws lambda it was not appropriate to compile a native bcrypt package that works on lambda. crypto worked fine!